# Problems with PayPal IPN - redirect and post data

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

After users have been redirected to PayPal and completed the payment, they get redirected back to my site (ipn.php). However, it turns out it only sends back the user using HTTP get method.

I'm using the following IPN listener: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/blob/master/ipnlistener.php

However, it just says "Invalid HTTP request method" when user arrives on the ipn.php page. It's supposed to post back data and redirect the user. Am I missing a PayPal setting here or something?

Really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PayPal IPN does not occur when they redirect the users back to your site. Your users get redirected to a normal confirmation page.

The IPN request happens later. The delay can vary quite significantly and it only occurs when the transaction has been fully confirmed. It's essentially a webservice call from PayPal to your system.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed this after submitting on Stackoverflow. The payment system works perfectly. Have a nice day :)